# How do I navigate ifdef structures using atom-editor?

Tags: atom-editor

Is there a way to navigate `#ifdef` structures in atom?

```
#ifdef EXAMPLE
...
code
...
#else
...
more code
...
#endif
```

If I am at the `#ifdef` and I want to navigate to the `#else` or the `#endif`, is there a way to do that within atom?

I can perform searches, but it becomes tedious if you have multiple nested `#ifdef` structures. You have to try and track each `#ifdef` manually and hope you don't lose track. If you have a lot of `#ifdef` it becomes increasingly tedious to search.

Atom can quickly navigate brackets using `Ctrl+M`. This doesn't work for `#ifdef` structures and I'm wondering if there's a shortcut.